Why didn't Bishop photograph the man that talked to Elizabeth?
During the Beirut portion of Muir & Bishop's affairs, there is a part where Bishop meets Elizabeth Hadley. He gets closer to her by helping with the supplies for a refugee camp she works at. When they are delivered, Bishop is seen taking photos of the camp from afar. At some point, a man approaches Hadley and they talk (seemingly as friends or acquaintances) and we see Bishop starting to take the photo of them as well but hesitating and opting not to in the end.
We know that Bishop develops feelings for her eventually although it's not clear if it's before or after this episode. We also know that those photos were meant to end up in CIA's hands.
What was his reason for not taking that photo of a man talking to Hadley?
It seemed like a move that could jeopardize their operation. And indeed we see Muir scolding him for not knowing that the man was involved with Hezbollah.
It also seems that personal feelings for Hadley could not be the motive for skipping that picture because nothing would prevent Bishop from keeping his relationship with Hadley on a strictly personal level without involving her in any CIA stuff (however I might be wrong here).

Its just an indicator to let the audience know that Bishop has fallen for her, and in not taking the photo, is choosing to turn a blind eye to how she operates and who with, and to not implicate her, which would ruin his chance of an intimate relationship with her, and would also distract from what he is really doing, which is establishing a rapport with Ahmed, hoping to turn him into an asset.
If it was just another job, and she is just a means to an end, he would have taken her photo with the contact, and just let it go through the office, the analysts, and the motions; and its likely she would have been flagged.
But, although he has already established a working relationship (hence the smuggling of aid through the checkpoints), he is now falling for her, and the hesitation is the nod to the audience to show this event occurred.
Note that Bishop has seen the man before - he was seen with Elizabeth (drinking, smoking, laughing, so clearly very familiar with eachother) in the café of The Commodore, an ex-pat hangout, when Muir's voice over was talking about sending Bishop into Beirut a couple of months before to set up contacts for the operation, so he probably had an idea that the man might be trouble in the first place, and seeing her with him again at the camp probably confirmed it, but he didn't want to get Elizabeth flagged, due to his personal feelings for her (but not knowing that there was a file on her already).
This is not in the early script draft, so there isn't any other easily accessible source for the shooting script to confirm it.
